# Bluebird unhandled Error with emit NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

im using Bluebird v2.8.2 Promises, but im getting unhandled error and code in catch is not processed.

**EDITED to respones:**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
    util = require('util')
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Module = function() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
};

util.inherits(Module, EventEmitter);

var getData = function() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('test'));
};


Module.prototype.getCustomer = function() {
    var self = this;        

    setTimeout(function() {
        getData().then(function() {})
            .catch(function(error) {
                self.emit('error', error); // This causes problem!!
            });
    }, 1000);
}
```

**SOLVED:** 
Last comment of Esailija

Comment: Don't mix callbacks, promises and event emitters, only one is truly necessary because most of the time event emitter events map to different resolution or rejection values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is  processed just fine, however most likely your code inside the catch handler had a bug and threw an error. I suggest you read the printed unhandled error more carefully to see what it is.

The equivalent synchronous code would behave same way:

```
   try {
        throw new Error("test");
   } catch (e) {
        causesUnhandledReferenceError;
   }
```

If you wanted to catch that error (You certainly don't, just for exercise) you would need another try catch:

```
try {
    throw new Error("test");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        doesntCauseUnhandledReferenceError;
    } catch (e) {
        // logs reference error
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Similarly with promises:

```
getData().then(function() {

}).catch(function(e) {
    doesntCauseUnhandledReferenceError;
}).catch(function(e) {
      // logs reference error
      console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: I tried your test, but there is no bug. When i tried replace Error fe. with CustomError, that catch error is instance of CustomError.

Comment: I found what causes a problem, i rewrited whole question. getCustomer now returning unhandled error. Problem is, when ill use emit from EventEmmiter. But why ?

Comment: @Nehalem did you read event emitter docs? "Error events are treated as a special case in node. If there is no listener for it, then the default action is to print a stack trace and exit the program." Your question is unrelated to promises

Comment: Oh, thats it. Sry, i didnt saw that. Thank you very much for point it out.